# Exchange 2010 DAG DAC mode would prevent having some databases active on secondary site?

Tags: exchange-2010, dag, windows

If I have a two nodes Exchange 2010 DAG stretched over two sites with DAC mode enabled and all databases active on primary site, I would still be able to activate some databases on the secondary site without do a complete datacenter switchover?